# How can I drop rows that contain any string in python / pandas

Tags: pandas

I would like to remove rows who contain a string / value in a column (not a specific string). In other words, if a column is filled with any kind of value the row should be deleted completely.

In this example the the row 2 and Row 4 should be deleted because in column secret there is a value

[image: output expected]

```
data = [['Alex',10,''],['John',12,'Name is Secret'],['Ben',13,''],['Steeve',13,'1']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age','secret'])

indexDelete = df[ df['secret'] == '*'].index

df.drop(indexDelete , inplace=True)
```

Comment: The rows you want to keep still contain empty strings. You could filter to just empty strings if this is expected or do you want to only keep rows that have `NaN` in the cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df[df['secret'].str.len() == 0]
```

This removes any rows that have empty string as a value.

Not sure that this is exactly what you are looking for.